# Is there a New Line equivalent of the No-Break Space Unicode character?

Tags: html, unicode

I am looking for a way to force a new line / break line in a HTML text box. It's a "description" box and I need to convey a bunch of information (main description, multiple download links, social media links, ...), and would like to give it a slightly nicer, more readable spacing.

The box' line breaking works the same as it does here on Stackoverflow:

- breaking the line once in the editor, results in the lines of text staying together in the rendering.
- breaking the line twice, results in a new paragraph with a small whitespace in front.
- breaking the line three or more times, does the same as just doing it twice.

And I can only input flat text, but on my Mac, I can press Alt+Space to type the Unicode character for a No-Break Space (" "), with the same result as if I added **& nbsp;** into the HTML file. Together with "•" (Shift+Alt+.), this works perfectly to force the appearance of an unordered list (even nested ones, if I want to).

So now I'm looking for a way to do the same with a New Line, so I can better space out my blocks of information. Any ideas?

PS: I know this will make a lot of web developers cringe, but because I'm just using Unicode characters, it won't break anything. If the site expects you to post download links and contact information, why didn't they just provide segments for those, to do it correctly, instead of just a single "Description" box? There are separate boxes for "Technology used" and "Help / Controls", so why not for "Download", "Contact Info", ...? :/

PPS: I guess forcing a horizontal rule would be fine too (and maybe look even better)

Comment: `U+a`
line feed (lf) - end of line - eol - new line - html entities...

Comment: Oh, right, you mean the alt+code thing?
http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character

I'll have to figure out how to do that on a Mac!